# Not receiving payload from Slack Slash Commands API

Tags: php, slack

I created slack app and command. But when command is executed,  I don't get payload to my external url and it were called as I can see logs. Here is php script

```
file_put_contents('1.txt', var_export($_POST, true));
```

and result is empty array in the file. I debuged the call and I can't see any params with payload data.

EDIT
Here is SERVER data

```
UNIQUE_ID = "Xm99Z8CoAMcAAJ@MNFgAAAA8"
HTTP_USER_AGENT = "Slackbot 1.0 (+https://api.slack.com/robots)"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = "gzip,deflate"
HTTP_ACCEPT = "application/json,*/*"
HTTP_X_SLACK_SIGNATURE = "v0=3f8b04f0d2b720ee962accebb7b5cc9d56ed4d0a42d6bda766ee2c229fa1c2d2"
HTTP_X_SLACK_REQUEST_TIMESTAMP = "1584364905"
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL = "max-age=259200"
HTTP_CONNECTION = "keep-alive"
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\compiler;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;"
SystemRoot = "C:\WINDOWS"
COMSPEC = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
PATHEXT = ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC"
WINDIR = "C:\WINDOWS"
SERVER_SIGNATURE = ""
SERVER_SOFTWARE = "Apache/2.2.31 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2h mod_fcgid/2.3.9 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 PHP/7.2.14 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.16.3"
SERVER_ADDR = "192.168.0.199"
SERVER_PORT = "80"
REMOTE_ADDR = "34.229.48.226"
DOCUMENT_ROOT = "W:/webserver2/home/trello/www"
SERVER_ADMIN = "testemail@test.com"
SCRIPT_FILENAME = "W:/webserver2/home/trello/www/trel/index.php"
REMOTE_PORT = "65052"
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = "CGI/1.1"
SERVER_PROTOCOL = "HTTP/1.1"
REQUEST_METHOD = "GET"
QUERY_STRING = ""
REQUEST_URI = "/trel/"
SCRIPT_NAME = "/trel/index.php"
PHP_SELF = "/trel/index.php"
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT = 1584364903.926
REQUEST_TIME = 1584364903
```

Comment: What are they sending - JSON? If so, this way please … https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php

Comment: @CBroe they send nothing at all. phpinput is empty to, no post, json or other request. I have updated my post with SERVER data

Comment: Is this actually “online”, or are you just trying this on your local development machine …?

Comment: @CBroe its online, I have real address so request reaches to my local machine, and thus I can debug etc

Comment: It says `REQUEST_METHOD = "GET"` in the debug output you have shown - is it supposed to be that, or rather a POST? If the latter, then check if you have any redirects going on on your end for the target URL you specified.

Comment: @CBroe it seems my webserver doesn't accept json request by some reason. I just tested and plain text appeared on phpinput but if select application/json params are absent

Comment: @CBroe some miracle, now I get such requests. I don't know why. I set command url to test end point in the network, then back to my url and it works without problem. My brains are boiling